# How do I make items that are in one div display separatly in different positions

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, flexbox

[image]I have looped through some names and I am accessing them from one div as such  {{item}} 
They are all in one parent.

This is my code

```
<div 
  :style="image"
  class="main-browse">
  <div
    id="first"
    class="names"
    v-for="(user, index) in getUsers" 
    :key="user.id"
  >
    <div
      id='user'
      :style="{backgroundColor: getColors[index]}">
      <div>{{user.name[0]}}</div>
      
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

and CSS

```
#user{
    padding: 10px; 
    margin: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;  
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  .names{
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    position: unset;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 2.5;
  }
```

They are moving all together as one item. but i want all the individual names to pick flex rules and fall at different places.

Comment: I think all you need to do is add `position:absolute` to your classes

Comment: that didnt work

Comment: Yes sorry. You should add `x:` and `y:` position coordinates on your styles also

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here, and I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Adding a picture of the correct design would be helpful to understand the goal. That said, I'll do my best here.

First, you have your `v-for` is on the `#first` div which means you're going to get a `#first` for every user in `getUsers`. Ids should be unique and that's going to give you multiple `#first` ids. This is the reason that your names are stacking and aren't flexing, you're only flexing one item inside of each `.names`. Your compiled markup is rendering something like this:

```
<div class="main-browser">
  <div id="first" class="names">
    <div id="user">H</div>
  </div>
  <div id="first" class="names">
    <div id="user">L</div>
  </div>
  <div id="first" class="names">
    <div id="user">N</div>
  </div>
  <div id="first" class="names">
    <div id="user">K</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My guess is that you actually want to have the `v-for` on `#user` and not `#first`. Again, using an id here is going to give you similar issues as above, so I'd change this to `.user`. I believe you want this markup:

```
<div :style="image" class="main-browser">
  <div class="names">
    <div
      v-for="(user, index) in getUsers" 
      :key="user.id"
      class="user"
      :style="{backgroundColor: getColors[index]}">
      <div>{{user.name[0]}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would render out to something like this:

```
<div class="main-browser">
  <div class="names">
    <div class="user">H</div>
    <div class="user">L</div>
    <div class="user">N</div>
    <div class="user">K</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By doing this, you're looping through the users on the user. This would give you the ability to render out as much as you want for each user.

Now, you would want to set `display: flex;` on `.names`. This will allow you to flex the names or in your case initials for each user and have them display in a row.

---

For the question, you have listed in the title, `items that are in one div display separately in different positions`, that really depends on what you're trying to do. If you're just trying to display in a row, then my work is done here - though you may need to add margins to get everything to display correctly.

If you're trying to put them somewhere specific, I'd start by applying a `position: relative;` to `.names` and then `position: absolute;` to everything below that. From there you just set the position of the items with `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`.